# Перерисовка окна при изменении его размера

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, resize

Только начал изучать DirectX и WinAPI. Написал простейшую программу: создаёт квадрат на всё окно и "раскрашивает" его шейдером. Но при уменьшении размера окна изображение сжимается, а при увеличении - растягивается. Как сделать, чтобы этого не происходило, т.е. при уменьшении, например, изображение не сжималось, а просто показывалась его меньшая область.
Пробывал сделать это так:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // ...

    switch (message)
    {
        // ...

        case WM_SIZE:
            D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
            vp.Width = (FLOAT)LOWORD(lParam);
            vp.Height = (FLOAT)HIWORD(lParam);
            vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
            vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
            vp.TopLeftX = 0;
            vp.TopLeftY = 0;
            if (g_pImmediateContext)
                g_pImmediateContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
        break;

        // ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Думал, сработает, но получил странное поведение: при уменьшении размера окна изображение ещё сильнее уменьшается, а при увеличении остаётся неизменным. Как реализовать описанное ранее поведение правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вне зависимости от фактических размеров окна его DirectX-ная система координат всегда будет описывать прямоугольник *(0, 0)-(1, 1)* (DX10) или *(-1, -1)-(1, 1)* (DX9). Для этого DirectX будет специально масштабировать (а в DX9 ещё и перемещать) координаты на кадровом буфере.

Соответственно, ваша задача заключается в применении матрицы трансформации, которая отменяла бы подобный эффект, «сжимая» обе координаты прямо пропорционально габаритам окна. Причём эта матрица должна применяться *после* применения всех остальных матриц, если они есть.

Для DirectX 11 (упомянутого в вопросе) матрица будет иметь следующий вид:

> [image]
>
> где:
>
> - α — масштабный коэффициент, указывающий, сколько пикселей должно приходиться на единичный отрезок обзорной области.
> - w, h — ширина и высота клиентской области окна; получать при каждом `WM_SIZE` с помощью `LOWORD(lParam)` и `HIWORD(lParam)` соответственно.